# Data is not shown in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have the following code:

```
package view;

import base.BaseView;
import contoller.EvaluatePropertyController;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class EvaluatePropertyWindow extends JFrame implements BaseView {
    private EvaluatePropertyController controller = new EvaluatePropertyController();

    private JLabel queryLB = new JLabel("Запрос: ");
    private JTextArea queryTA = new JTextArea();
    private JTable table = new JTable();
    private Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();
    private JButton backBtn = new JButton("Назад");
    private JButton executeBtn = new JButton("Выполнить");


    private int id;
    private MenuWindow window;

    EvaluatePropertyWindow(int id, MenuWindow window) {
        super("Конструктор отчетов");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.id = id;
        this.window = window;
        controller.attachView(this);
        controller.setId(id);
        initWindow();
    }


    public void onDataSaved() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Info saved", "Saved!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void initWindow() {
        SpringLayout springLayout = new SpringLayout();
        getContentPane().setLayout(springLayout);

        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.HORIZONTAL_CENTER, table, 0, SpringLayout.HORIZONTAL_CENTER, getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, table, 20, SpringLayout.NORTH, getContentPane());

        getContentPane().add(queryLB);
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, queryLB, 20, SpringLayout.WEST, table);
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, queryLB, 20, SpringLayout.NORTH, getContentPane());

        getContentPane().add(queryTA);
        queryTA.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, queryTA, 20, SpringLayout.EAST, queryLB);
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, queryTA, 20, SpringLayout.NORTH, getContentPane());


        getContentPane().add(executeBtn);
        executeBtn.addActionListener(e -> {
            String query = queryTA.getText().replace('\n', ' ');
            controller.executeQueries(query);
            //System.out.println(query);
        });

        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.HORIZONTAL_CENTER, executeBtn, 0, SpringLayout.HORIZONTAL_CENTER, queryTA);
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, executeBtn, 20, SpringLayout.SOUTH, queryTA);


        getContentPane().add(backBtn);
        backBtn.addActionListener(e -> {
            this.setVisible(false);
            window.setVisible(true);
        });

        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.HORIZONTAL_CENTER, backBtn, 0, SpringLayout.HORIZONTAL_CENTER, executeBtn);
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, backBtn, 20, SpringLayout.SOUTH, executeBtn);


        setSize(900, 800);
    }

    public void setColumnNames(List<String> columns) {
        columnNames.clear();
        columnNames.addAll(columns);
    }

    public void onLoaded(Vector<Vector> data) {
        table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println(columnNames);
    }

}
```

So, there's `onLoaded` method in the window class, which sets column Names and table data. But when I run the app I got the following output:

[image]

The result of

```
System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println(columnNames);
```

is `[[1, nick, 123, @mail.ru, 1]] [u_id, u_login, u_password, u_email, u_role]`, so data is received correctly. So, why there's no data loaded to JTable?

**UPD**

Modified code in this way:

```
    public void onLoaded(Vector<Vector> data) {
        data.forEach(it -> {
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).addRow(it);
        });
        System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println(columnNames);

        String name = "output" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".txt";
}
```

Still shows nothing, but the output of `data` is an array of an empty object: [[]]

Comment: You create a new JTable, but then do nothing with it. Thus, the newly created table is garbage collected and disappears. Its is never displayed.

Comment: @Polygnome updated the question

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table, or form it from known sources (fonts, locales etc.) 2)  `queryTA.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));` See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) The size of a text area can be suggested by setting the number of rows & columns of test it needs to hold.

Answer (score 1):

So there are 2 issues:

1. You create a new `JTable` instance on each call of `onLoaded` and set the data to the new instance, which doesn't help as you should really be modifying the current `JTable` you have added
2. In order to completely update/refresh a `JTable`s data (which I assume is what you want as when a query is run you wouldn't want to append new data to old) you would need to extend the `DefaultTableModel` and create a method which accepts and sets the new data and then fires `fireTableDataChanged()`.

Here is an example of the below:
[image]

**CustomTableModel.java:**

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class CustomTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    public CustomTableModel(Object[][] data, String[] columnNames) {
        super(data, columnNames);
    }

    public void setData(Object[][] data) {
        this.setDataVector(convertToVector(data), this.columnIdentifiers);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

**TestApp.java:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TestApp {

    private JTable table;

    public TestApp() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(TestApp::new);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestApp");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        // setup refresh data button
        JButton refreshButton = new JButton("Refresh data");
        refreshButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            // lets update the data using a swing worker to not freeze the UI
            new SwingWorker<Object[][], Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Object[][] doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    return getRandomData();
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    try {
                        // get the data and update the table
                        Object[][] data = get();
                        ((CustomTableModel) table.getModel()).setData(data);
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(TestApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }.execute();
        });

        table = new JTable() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        // setup JTable and custom table model with intial data
        Object[][] data = getRandomData();
        String[] columnNames = {"Random Data"};
        CustomTableModel model = new CustomTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table.setModel(model);

        // add components to the panel
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(refreshButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private Object[][] getRandomData() {
        Object[][] data = {{UUID.randomUUID()}, {UUID.randomUUID()}, {UUID.randomUUID()}, {UUID.randomUUID()}, {UUID.randomUUID()}, {UUID.randomUUID()}};
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onLoaded is called, but you just asign a value and do not add to the screen

```
table = new JTable(data, columnNames); // this creates instance and nothing else
```

your solution is put this new created JTable on the screen or use the old one reference and set the data there trough its `TableModel`

Comment: Updated the question